# How to calculate $V(X+Y)$ with $X$,$Y$ dependent?

Tags: probability, covariance

I want to calculate the covariance of two **dependent** variables $X$ and $Y$ and I don't know the value of $V(X+Y)$, that is, the variance of $X+Y$.

I know how the quantities relate to each other:

$$V(X+Y) = V(X) + V(Y) + 2\,\text{cov}(X,Y)$$

but I don't know how to calculate at least one of them without the other. Any tips?

I know the distributions of both $X$ and $Y$ but not the joint distribution.

Comment: You could try computing $Cov(X,Y) = E[XY]-E[X]E[Y]$. That may be possible since you know the distributions of X and Y

Comment: I tried that, but turns out $E[XY]$ depends on $V(X+Y)$, as coffemath's awnser to this question points out: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/350555/find-exy-assuming-no-independence-given-find-exy-with-ex-4-ey-10-v

Answer (score 1):

As you note, $$Var(X+Y)=Var(X)+Var(Y)+2Cov(X,Y)$$
where $Cov(X,Y)=E(XY)-E(X)E(Y)$. If you know the variables $X$ and $Y$, then you can compute the variance of their sum directly, as $$Var(X+Y)=\sum_{x,y}((x+y)-(E(X)+E(Y))^{2}P(X=x,Y=y)$$
or you can compute $E(XY)$ directly, as $$\sum_{x,y}xyP(X=x,Y=y)$$
You just have to treat $X+Y$ and $XY$ as random variables (which they are!).

Answer (score 0):

If $X$ and $Y$ are discrete, you can calculate the covariance using the formula $$\textrm{cov}(X,Y)=\sum\sum(x-\mu_X)(y-\mu_Y)f(x,y)$$
where you carry out the sum over the whole domains of both variables. If they are continuous, you may similarly use the formula $$\textrm{cov}(X,Y)=\iint (x-\mu_X)(y-\mu_Y)f(x,y) \,dx\,dy$$
where you again integrate over the whole domain. Both formulas come from the definition of covariance:
$$\textrm{cov}(X,Y)=E[(X-\mu_X)(Y-\mu_Y)]$$

Of course, all of this assumes that you know the joint distribution $f(x,y)$. Otherwise, it's possible you don't have enough information to answer the question.

Comment: In his question the OP says: *I know the distributions of both X and Y but not the joint distribution*.

Comment: @Karl: This was an edit made after my answer was posted. I'll ask OP (if they happen to see this) to describe exactly what information they have on hand, but it seems likely that the question is unanswerable.

Comment: Your awnser was good @DivergentQueries as you did not know yet that I didn't know what the joint distribution was. I guess there is no awnser to this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If you know the correlation coefficient, $\rho_{XY}$, $Var(X)$ and $Var(Y)$, you can compute the covariance via the relationship: $$\rho_{XY}= \frac{Cov(X, Y)}{\sqrt{Var(X)Var(Y)}}$$

$$Cov(X,Y) = \rho_{XY}\sqrt{Var(X)Var(Y)}$$

Then you can compute $Var(X+Y) = Var(X) + Var(Y) + 2Cov(X,Y)$.